# TensorFlow Error: OP_REQUIRES failed at summary_kernels.cc:65 - Not a directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, directory

I'm encountering an issue while using TensorFlow's TensorBoard callback in my code. I have a section of code dedicated to training and saving a model, and I'm trying to use the TensorBoard callback for logging. However, I'm facing the following error:

```
2024-01-16 14:38:37.761439: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1839] OP_REQUIRES failed at summary_kernels.cc:65 : FAILED_PRECONDITION: Not a directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: {{function_node __wrapped__CreateSummaryFileWriter_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Not a directory [Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter] name:
```

#### Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Section 3: Training & Save Model
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

epochs = 30
batch_size = 16

# Save logs of the model for TensorBoard
NAME = "LSTM-64-{}".format(int(time.time()))

# Get the current working directory
cwd = os.getcwd()

# Define the log directory
logdir = os.path.join(cwd, "logs", NAME)

# Create the log directory if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(logdir, exist_ok=True)

# Create a TensorBoard callback
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir, histogram_freq=1)



model.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_split=0.1,
        callbacks=[tensorboard])   # add [cp_callback]
```

#### What I know so far:

- The "logs" directory gets created successfully.
- I've tried both relative and absolute paths for the log directory (current implementation is absolute).
- I printed the **`logdir`** variable, and it seems correct.
- When I add other callbacks like **`ModelCheckpoint`** from Keras, there is no issue in the **`fit`** function.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this error or how to debug it would be greatly appreciated!